# Class Not Registered error creating an instance of a COM Server interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, com, interop

There is a third-party COM server DLL I need to include in my ASP.NET Core project. Adding via the *Add > COM Reference* worked fine and I end up with a *COM > Interop.ThirdPartyServer* under the *Dependencies*.

In my code I want to create an instance of one of the classes but it keeps failing with "Class not registered" even though it is.

I used

```
using ThirdPartyServer;

Type widgetType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ThirdPartyServer.Widget");

IWidget myWidget = (IWidget)Activator.CreateInstance(widgetType);
```

But I am seeing a **"80040154 Class not registered"** error.

I am sure it is registered, as I had to find the *ProgID* from the registry as it's not shown anywhere in the disassembled type library. In any case, I re-ran `regsvr32 ThirdPartyServer.dll` and that seemed to work with no errors, as it is a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: Make sure the calling code runs with the same bitness as the registry where it was registered (calling from x64 code => needs to be registered in x64 registry, calling from x86 code => needs to be registered in x86 registry)

Comment: @SimonMourier. You're a legend. Make your comment an answer so I can mark it as such. Had to change the platform target to **x86** instead of **Any CPU**. Will talk to the third-party company to see if they have, or intend to release, a x64 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0x80040154` aka `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` or "Class not registered" error usually means ... well, that the class is ... not registered. But the exact reason can be a bit complex.

COM clients and COM servers that run both in-process need to run with the same bitness, so both in x86 or both in x64. So:

- If a COM client runs as x86, it talks to the x86 side of the
  registry, so the COM server must registered in the x86 side of the
  registry (regsvr32, regasm, custom reg code, etc. must run as x86).
- If a COM client runs as x64, it talks to the x64 side of the
  registry, so the COM server must registered in the x64 side of the
  registry (regsvr32, regasm, custom reg code, etc. must run as x64).

Note 1: for out-of-process communications x86 clients or servers can talk to x64 servers or clients. That's one benefit of COM.

Note 2: the .NET "Any CPU" compilation feature allows to use the exact same binary for x86 and x64 but this binary still needs to be registered in the needed registry side, or in both registry sides if x86 clients and x64 clients support is needed.